# How to render the Greek word "philotimo/filotimo" in French?

Tags: expressions, traduction, grec

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philotimo

> Philotimo is considered to be the highest of all Greek virtues, the
>   standards for family and social living; the core concept is that of
>   respect and walking in the right paths. In its simplest form, the term
>   means "doing good", actions that show a man's behavior as being exemplary and taken with fortitude according to an ideal upbringing the philotimo way. Philotimo to a Greek is essentially a way of life.
>
> Children are said to display philotimo when they display unconditional
>   love and respect towards their parents, grandparents and friends, even
>   through small actions such as expressions of gratitude for small gifts
>   or random acts of kindness. It extends to include appreciation and
>   admiration for heritage and ancestors. The concept was used to embody
>   the assistance rendered to Allied soldiers on Crete after the Axis
>   invasion of the island; locals felt driven by philotimo to hide
>   Australians and Britons despite the death penalty for sheltering
>   soldiers.

https://greece.greekreporter.com/2013/06/08/filotimo-the-hard-to-translate-greek-word/

> Filotimo or philotimo is a Greek noun comprised of the words philo
>   (verb translated as “to like” or noun translating as “friend”) and
>   timo (verb translating as “to honor”). It is hard to explain,
>   impossible to translate in one word in any other language and so
>   commonly used among Greeks that it is somehow believed that you are
>   actually born with it and must stand up for it all your life. And just
>   because filotimo represents a way of life for Greeks it includes ideas
>   and virtues such as honor, justice, courage, dignity, pride, self
>   sacrifice, respect, freedom, gratitude and hospitality.

https://www.helleniccomserve.com/filotimo.html

> The most untranslatable, demanding and really mysterious word in the
>   Greek language is the word Filotimo. Literally, of course, it means
>   friend of honor. But Filotimo is exceedingly much, much more.
>
> I think it was the philosopher Thales who said, "Filotimo to the Greek
>   is like breathing. A Greek is not a Greek without it. He might as well
>   not be alive."

The closest to the meaning of the word that I found (in French) is here

https://europeisnotdead.com/europe-is-not-deadfr/disco/mots-europeens/mots-intraduisibles-europeens/

> Filotimo – Filotimo signifie littéralement un ami d’honneur, mais
>   implique aussi de la dignité, de la fierté, du sacrifice et du
>   respect. Le philosophe Thales  disait: «Filotimo pour un grec, c’est
>   comme respirer. Un grec n’est pas un Grec sans cela. Il pourrait tout
>   aussi bien ne pas être en vie sans.”

but I am wondering if there are other French words or expressions that convey similar ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il n'y a aucun mot, donc aucun concept reconnu dans la culture française qui approche le concept du filotimo et il est probable que très peu d'esprit rationnels français puissent penser qu'un tel amalgame justifie un mot ; les liens ne peuvent être jugés que comme étant trop arbitraires.

Le concept français « entier » qui se rapprocherait le plus de ce « concept aux multiples tentacules » serait celui de **l'altruisme**. En voici la définition à partir du TLFi;

> A. PSYCHOL. Disposition bienveillante à l'égard des autres, fondée sur la sympathie. Synon. philanthropie
>    Spéc., chez A. Comte. Disposition organique; ensemble des penchants sympathiques innés, tels que l'affection, la vénération, le dévouement
>   B. MOR. Conduite de l'homme responsable qui pose comme but de l'activité morale l'intérêt de ses semblables. Quasi-synon. abnégation, générosité;

Ce n'est pas une qualité de l'être humain qui soit vénérée comme le filotimo en Grèce ; la culture française est fondée sur ce principe, parmi quelques autres ; la politique en particulier, du moins depuis la révolution de 1789 peut être reconnue comme ayant une assise d'altruisme indéniable. Cependant cette qualité n'est pas vénérée ; les principes qui la caractérisent sont vantés mais l'état d'esprit qui les sous-tend n'est pas mis en avant, pas rendu explicite aux enfants dans les école comme élément d'un catéchisme national ; c'est au philosophe à comprendre cet état d'esprit fondamental. Il ne faut pas oublier non plus qu'il n'est pas à dissocier de la culture religieuse. 
On utilise le terme, mais à un niveau de langue formel, élevé ou comme la définition le montre dans les études de  psychologie et de philosophie (question d'éthique, de morale). C'est donc un concept assez difficile à invoquer dans la conversation courante. Des termes plus courants, mais plus restreints dans leur portée, et plus aisés à utiliser, bien que l'on ne les trouvera que  dans les propos de personnes de sensibilité peu ordinaire sont les termes « **amour du prochain** » et « **amour de son prochain** ». On peut donc dire « par amour du prochain » ou « par altruisme » lorsque l'on parle d'actions dont la motivation est au moins en partie le souhait de faire du bien, cela parce que le terme « altruisme » englobe dans sa définition celle de ces termes.

L'altruisme est bien un terme de la même nature malgré sa portée moins universelle et sa nature de norme non explicite relativement au filotimo. Par exemple l'honneur et la famille ne sont pas des concept dans lesquels l'altruisme soit un principe servant à justifier quoi que ce soit : l'amour familial sous toutes ses facettes ne se confond pas avec l'amour du prochain (lequel est de l'altruisme).

Ce qui manque essentiellement pour avoir fait le tour du filotimo sont les deux derniers concepts introduits, l'amour familial et l'honneur; l'honneur, chose pas si étrange puisque l'élément responsable de la société est toujours l'homme, mais chose bien connue, reste le privilège et le fardeau de l'homme dans la société humaine, bien que beaucoup de changements aient pris place ; c'est pour cette raison que l'on entendra [souvent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=femme+de+parole%2Chomme+de+parole&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfemme%20de%20parole%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chomme%20de%20parole%3B%2Cc0) l'expression « un homme de parole » et très rarement une « femme de parole ». Néanmoins, cette culture de l'homme de parole est toujours vivante. Ce qui de nos jours n'a plus tout à fait la place privilégiée que les temps passés lui avait conservée, c'est l'idéal familial mais il subsiste de même que l'idéal patriotique.

Si on doit trouver non pas un mot mais un terme qui corresponde à ce que l'on trouve dans la culture française on peut énoncer « **altruisme, famille, honneur et patrie** » comme étant  à peu près la même chose.

Comment: Pour Ulysse, *l’hospitalité* en est-elle le reflet ?

Comment: @cl-r Vous voulez dire la Maison d'Ulysse ?

Comment: Dans l’Odyssée, l’hospitalité est une exigence (voire une loi) contrôlée par les dieux : principe de relations inter-cité, reconnaissance de l’Autre (même étranger respectueux des lois grecques) … ces notions impliquent-elles le *philotimo*  ?

Comment: @cl-r Je ne saurais dire ; mais comme Thalès en parle, donc avant la date où on situe l'Odyssée d'après les vérifications que je viens de faire, il est fort possible qu'il ne s'agisse pas d'autre chose que de ce fameux filotimo.

Answer (score 1):

S'il fallait utiliser un seul mot pour tenter de sous-entendre l'ensemble des qualités décrites dans l'article de Wikipedia, je dirais :

> l'[exemplarité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exemplarit%C3%A9)

dans le sens conduite, comportement [exemplaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exemplaire), c'est à dire  *qui peut être cité en exemple, en modèle à imiter.*

Answer (score 1):

Ayant reconnu que le sens souhaité par l'OP n'a pas nécessairement d'équivalent français, le *φιλότιμο* grec-ancien n'en reste pas nécessairement intraduisible.

Dans la plupart des textes classiques (et en particulier ceux de Platon), il est principalement pris en mauvaise part au point que Bailly (2081 et suiv.) donne en premier sens pour *φιλοτιμια* celui d'*ambition / zèle* et conséquemment *ambitieux / zélé* pour le *φιλότιμος*.