# Mots et expressions français intraduisibles

Tags: traduction

Ayant posé bien des questions concernant des mots grecs qui sont difficiles à traduire ou à interpréter en français (voire intraduisibles) ; voir [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33718/traduction-du-mot-grec-kala%C3%ADsthitos/33719#33719), [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33931/traduction-du-mot-grec-klaus%C3%ADgel%C3%B4s) et [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33393/how-to-render-the-greek-word-philotimo-filotimo-in-french/33420#33420) (il en existe évidement [d'autres](https://matadornetwork.com/read/11-untranslatable-greek-phrases-need-english/)) je me demande quels mots français et quelles expressions françaises sont pareillement difficiles à traduire ou à rendre en autres langues, par exemple, en anglais. Je pense à *chez* et *Bérézina* et j'ai vu le contenu de cet [article en ligne](https://www.courslangues.com/paris/cours-francais/mots-francais-intraduisibles) mais je voudrais voir d'autres exemples.

Comment: Je trouve le concept de *flemme* assez compliquer à traduire et même à expliquer à des non-francophones.

Comment: le concept de *flemme* peut simplement être expliqué by being/feeling tired

Comment: on pourrait traduire *flemme* par *being lazy to do something*, du moins c'est ce qui ce rapproche le plus ;)

Comment: @Ced Non c'est pas juste de la fatigue, c'est entre la fatigue et la paresse. Et en plus que le concept en lui-même, je trouve ça dur de traduire des phrases comme "*J'ai la flemme de faire ça*" ou "*Pfff... la flemme...*"

Comment: +1. @TeleportingGoat Il y a bien ‘I can't be bothered to X’ qui dénote le manque de motivation, mais je préfère penser que notre langue a le monopole de ce concept :)

Comment: On trouve « to have a lazy fit » pour « avoir la flemme » ; « flemme » me semble correspondre essentiellement à « laziness ».

Comment: On trouve autre chose dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie, qui va plus loin que le TLFi, lequel ne fait de « flemme » qu'un synonyme de « paresse » ou tout aussi bien sans nuance supplémentaire « fainéantise » ; il s'agirait de paresse ou d'un « sentiment d'indolence » (définition : paresse, indolence) ; il y a donc bien quelque chose en plus mais ce n'est toujours pas un mélange de paresse et d'indolence : l'indolence n'est pas ressentie par l'indolent, c'est son état naturel et très couramment on dit « J'ai la flemme. ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Non peut-être !

C’est une expression plutôt belge qui signifie ironiquement « oui sûrement ! »

> C’est déjà bon!

Interjection de fin de phrase ou de fin conversation qui signifie un agacement, une envie d’en finir d’une situation particulière.

> Ça peut mal

Il n'y a pas de danger

> Chercher la misère

Chercher la querelle, les problèmes

> Il drache

Il pleut énormément

> Il n'a pas toutes ses frites dans le même sachet

Il n' a pas toute sa tête

> 100 balles ou sinon je remballe un Quick à Genval

Vas vite, rapidement

> Ou quoi, ou qu'est ce...

Ça veut rien dire de particulier, des fois les gens utilisent cette expression pour pas dire 'heueee'; ou à la place de excetera

J’en ai d'autres plutôt rigolotes, si vous en voulez plus; postez encore un message... ;)

Comment: Merci bien. Oui, je veux voir les autres mots/expressions dont vous parlez.

Comment: Mettre du beurre dans les épinards

Answer (score 1):

Le premier mot qui me vient à l'esprit est

> flâner = *se ballader sans but, en prenant son temps, en observant autour de soi*

Sinon on pourrait ajouter tous les mots qui sont utilisés tels quels en anglais comme

> bon appétit 
> et voilà!

Si je pense à d'autres mots je les rajouterai ;)

Comment: « et voilà » est utilisé mais il n'est pas exactement intraduisible tout le temps; les locutions « There you go! », « There you are! » semblent être l'équivalent au moins dans certain cas (used when showing or explaining something) ; exemple : « There you go ! Your car is working again ! ». Il faudrait montrer les cas particuliers où il n'y a plus un tel équivalent (ce que j'ai moi-même des difficultés à faire). Peut être celui-ci : « Et voilà, dix années ont passé et on n'a plus vingt ans. »

Comment: Pour flâner, il en y a pas mal: laze about, hang around, wander...

Answer (score 1):

Ça me refait penser à cette expression dont il a été question dans [cette question récente](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/33825/16656) :

> Se changer les idées

Expression toute bête qu'on utilise dans toutes sortes de circonstances. C'est sans doute celle qui me manque le plus en anglais.

Answer (score 1):

*Poil* ne peut pas se traduire de manière non ambiguë par un seul mot anglais.

Comment: Et surtout pile poil :-)

Answer (score 1):

Les termes suivants sont choisis en référence à l'anglais ; l'espagnol et l'italien aussi bien que l'allemand offrent parfois des possibilités : auf Wiedersehen, guten Tag, hasta la vista, bonjiorno, adios.

- Au revoir !
- À la prochaine !
- À l'année prochaine !
- Bonjour ! (« hello » or « hi » ne concernent pas la qualité de la journée de quelqu'un ; on retrouve cela seulement dans « good morning » et « good afternoon »)
- Adieu
- Monsieur  (*ou* Ce monsieur) (utilisé par le personnel qui reçoit les clients dans les magasins)
- je vous en prie (en réponse à « merci »)

Comment: See you, Good day (daté ou en Australie), Farewell

Comment: I remember reading Dumas' *Vignt Ans Après*, and thinking that *Au revoir, messieurs, en Angleterre,* (said by the villain) was wonderfully sinister, and that there was no good way to translate it. Of course *arrivederci* would probably work fine for this in Italian.

Comment: On ne dit pas 'a la prochaine fois', on dit 'a la prochaine'

Comment: @GeorgeM C'est exact, merci ; [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%80+la+prochaine+fois+%21%2C%C3%80+la+prochaine+%21&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%80%20la%20prochaine%20%21%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

- "N'importe quoi" (par ex. dans "C'est en faisant n'importe quoi qu'on devient n'importe qui").
- "midinette"

Comment: Aussi : *nawak*

Answer (score 1):

**Boîte**

Un ami Italien m’a fait remarquer qu’on utilise ce mot dans tellement de sens familiers différents, qu’aucun équivalent n’existe dans d’autres langues.

*Boîte* peut signifier discothèque, entreprise, moquerie (mettre en boîte), rectangle dans un schéma, chute ou ivresse (se prendre une boîte), et j’en oublie certainement.

Comment: *Boite à ouvrage*... et *c'est dans la boite* ;-)

Comment: Et lycée, comme dans _boîte à bac_.