# Interprétation de définitions de dictionnaire

Tags: dictionnaires, académie-française, définition

On trouve, par exemple dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie Française des définitions telles que la suivante, celle du mot « flemme » ;

> Pop. Paresse, indolence.

Dans un autre, le TLFi, pour le même mot on trouve ceci ;

> Fam. et pop. Sentiment de paresse, désir de ne rien faire.

Dans encore un autre, Le Larousse, c'est le  nouveau format suivant ;

> Familier Grande paresse ; envie de ne rien faire

On note que dans les deux premiers cas se trouvent deux descriptions mises en relation par une virgule et donc à première vue de deux définitions; est-on en présence

1. d'une qualification de la première par la seconde ?
2. d'une seule définition qui consiste en une évaluation au jugé par le  lecteur portant sur une combinaison (mystérieuse) des deux composantes ?
3. d'une paire de définitions, l'une et l'autre n'étant applicable essentiellement que seule selon le contexte ?

Si on s'en remet à la troisième définition, celle du Larousse, on est porté à croire qu'il s'agirait bien du cas « 3. ».

Apparemment il n'existe pas de convention bien précise sur l'usage de la virgule et du point-virgule ; serait-il cependant le cas  que l'interprétation de ces symboles diffère selon le dictionnaire ?

Comment lire ce type de définition en général dans les trois dictionnaires ?

Comment: Tu te fais des nœuds au cerveau... Les langues ne sont pas des sciences exactes.

Comment: Quand vous écrivez "deux-points" pensiez-vous plutôt "point-virgule" ?

Comment: Je suis curieux de savoir quelles sont les interprétations **différentes** de cette définition que tu es capable de lire en ayant cet affreux doute sur l'emploi de la virgule ou du point-virgule dans des définitions de moins de dix mots...

Comment: @jcm69 Oui, je ne vois pas ce qui m'a mis « deux-points » dans la tête ; merci de remarquer cela !

Comment: @Aweuzegaga Je dois avouer que je n'ai jamais eu de certitude sur ce point et cela m'a toujours gêné dans la lecture de certaines définitions ; je pensais que peut être quelque spécialiste ou autre intéressé aurait pu avoir une révélation utile sur l'ensemble ou même seulement sur les pratiques relatives à un seul dictionnaire. Cette question s'est finalement concrétisée dans mon esprit lorsque dans les commentaires d'une question quelqu'un a trouvé difficile de comprendre le mot « [flemme](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34000/17649) ».

Comment: Wiktionnaire donne 1) Paresse, envie de ne rien faire. 2) (Vieilli) Personne paresseuse. Soit avec virgule, soit avec point-virgule personnellement je ne vois qu'une seule définition (parlant du premier cas). +1 Quand même:-)!

Comment: Btw, il y une variante orthographique : flème (selon Wiktionnaire).

Comment: @dimitris <TLFi, état : B. Forme particulière d'un gouvernement; nature d'un régime politique. État populaire. Distinguons donc entre les prêtres dans un état monarchique et les prêtres dans une république (CHATEAUBR., Essai Révol., t. 2, 1797, p. 355). Il [un moine nommé Agaric] jugeait l'état démocratique contraire à la société sainte à laquelle il appartenait corps et âme (FRANCE, Île ping., 1908, p. 199).> Il y a une différence dans le présent cas (deux définitions) ; comment sait-on quand existe une différence et quand elle n'existe pas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les définitions des dictionnaires ne sont que des indices permettant au lecteur d'identifier le sens d'un mot à partir d'autres mots qu'il doit déjà connaître (ou apprendre). Les sens des mots d'une langue ne sont pas des entités indépendantes, cloisonnées, exclusives les unes des autres. Si un mot correspond à plusieurs sens liés, on trouvera une numérotation au sein de la même entrée, s'il s'agit d'homonymie et donc de sens sans rapport les uns avec les autres, on pourra trouver plusieurs entrées.

Il n'existe pas que je sache de convention particulière sur l'utilisation de la virgule ou du point-virgule dans un dictionnaire. Le point-virgule marque simplement une pause plus longue, mais n'introduit pas de rupture. On reste dans la même phrase.

[Dictionnaire:](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dictionnaire)

> **I.** − Recueil des mots d'une langue ou d'un domaine de l'activité humaine, réunis selon une nomenclature d'importance variable et présentés généralement par ordre alphabétique, **fournissant sur chaque mot un certain nombre d'informations relatives à son sens et à son emploi** et destiné à un public défini.

[Virgule:](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/virgule)

> **A.** −
>   **1.** Signe de ponctuation ayant la forme d'un petit trait courbé vers la gauche (,), placé à droite et au bas d'un mot **pour séparer les membres d'une phrase ou indiquer une pause faible**.

[Point-virgule:](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/point/1)

> **f)** Point-virgule et, vieilli, point et virgule. Signe de ponctuation (;) qui **sépare deux aspects d'une même idée [et] marque une pause un peu plus longue que la virgule**

Les sens des mots sont donc plutôt à considérer dans un espace à plusieurs dimensions, et plus ou moins proches les uns des autres en fonction des axes choisis.

Pour le mot *flemme*, on peut visualiser cet espace sémantique à l'aide de [l'outil suivant](http://crisco.unicaen.fr/espsem/flemme)  mis en ligne par le [CRISCO](http://crisco.unicaen.fr/) (Centre de recherches inter-langues sur la signification en contexte).

Il indique que *flemme* peut se situer dans la même enveloppe que *paresse*, *inertie*, et *fainéantise*, et qu'il est, suivant les axes considérés, plus proche d'inertie que les deux autres.

[image]

En creusant un peu à partir d'*indolence*, on peut afficher ce nouveau graphique assez intéressant, où la taille des points correspond à l'importance du mot dans l'univers sémantique du mot recherché :

[image]

et en partant de *paresse*, on retrouve la plupart des mots précédents, mais aussi de nouveau *flemme* que l'on peut alors situer :

[image]

Un projet similaire est proposé par le [CLLE](https://clle.univ-tlse2.fr/le-laboratoire-clle-369303.kjsp) (Laboratoire Cognition, Langues, Langage, Ergonomie) en collaboration avec [kodexlab](http://ww1.kodexlab.com/) est disponible à partir du portal CNRTL, voici la représentation de la proxémie du même mot [flemme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/proxemie/femme). Merci à jcm69 pour son commentaire le mentionnant !
[image]

Comment: Excellente réponse!

Comment: Bravo ! Au passage, le cnrtl propose quelque chose du même genre : http://www.cnrtl.fr/proxemie/flemme